# Reading local HTML files into R for data extraction

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I have a set of local html files in a folder. Using the code below I am able to import data. As a next step I want to merge a couple of files (all having same format), extract data and the contents into a tabular format for further analysis

```
source <- FactivaSource("page1.html")
corpus <- Corpus(source, readerControl = list(language = NA))
inspect(corpus)
meta(corpus[[1]])
```

Comment: Have a look into `rvest` package, which is really handy to deal with html info and extract data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to turn a corpus into a data frame is with `tidytext::tidy`, e.g.:

```r
library(tm)
library(tidytext)

data("crude") # crude dataset is from `tm` package
tidy(crude)
```

Once you've turned all your corpora into data frames you can combine them in whatever way makes sense - i.e. I would turn the corpora into data frames and then merge them, and not the other way around (although that's probably also possible).

**Output**:

```
> tidytext::tidy(crude)
# A tibble: 20 x 16
   author datetimestamp       description heading id    language origin topics lewissplit
   <chr>  <dttm>              <chr>       <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     
 1 NA     1987-02-26 18:00:56 ""          DIAMON… 127   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 2 BY TE… 1987-02-26 18:34:11 ""          OPEC M… 144   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 3 NA     1987-02-26 19:18:00 ""          TEXACO… 191   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 4 NA     1987-02-26 19:21:01 ""          MARATH… 194   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 5 NA     1987-02-26 20:00:57 ""          HOUSTO… 211   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 6 NA     1987-03-01 04:25:46 ""          KUWAIT… 236   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 7 By Je… 1987-03-01 04:39:14 ""          INDONE… 237   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 8 NA     1987-03-01 06:27:27 ""          SAUDI … 242   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
 9 NA     1987-03-01 09:22:30 ""          QATAR … 246   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
10 NA     1987-03-01 19:31:44 ""          SAUDI … 248   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
11 NA     1987-03-02 02:05:49 ""          SAUDI … 273   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
12 NA     1987-03-02 08:39:23 ""          GULF A… 349   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
13 NA     1987-03-02 08:43:22 ""          SAUDI … 352   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
14 NA     1987-03-02 08:43:41 ""          KUWAIT… 353   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
15 NA     1987-03-02 09:25:42 ""          PHILAD… 368   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
16 NA     1987-03-02 12:20:05 ""          STUDY … 489   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
17 NA     1987-03-02 12:28:26 ""          STUDY … 502   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
18 NA     1987-03-02 13:13:46 ""          UNOCAL… 543   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
19 By BE… 1987-03-02 15:38:34 ""          NYMEX … 704   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
20 NA     1987-03-02 15:49:06 ""          ARGENT… 708   en       Reute… YES    TRAIN     
# … with 7 more variables: cgisplit <chr>, oldid <chr>, places <named list>, people <chr>,
#   orgs <chr>, exchanges <chr>, text <chr>
```